# I'm looking for a way to use a hashmap with a key, value combination; used for rdfID mapping within an xml file

Tags: java, xml, replace, replaceall

I have an xml file which looks like this:

```
<cim:Terminal rdf:ID="6e5aba74-f8bf-4077-be5c-7058837e6990">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name>T1</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
<cim:Terminal.ConductingEquipment rdf:resource="#_CB_LAGN_LAGN_ANLK_CB_DUMCB"/>
<cim:Terminal.ConnectivityNode rdf:resource="#_ND_LAGN_LAGN_ANLK_34.5_1"/>
<cim:Terminal.sequenceNumber>1</cim:Terminal.sequenceNumber>
```

and

```
<cim:Breaker rdf:ID="a5f64f08-baac-457b-b11e-39ad990ececb">
<cim:IdentifiedObject.name>13676/DS</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
<cim:Switch.normalOpen>true</cim:Switch.normalOpen>
<cim:Equipment.EquipmentContainer rdf:resource="#_KV_LAGN_LAGN_CTWD_500"/>
```

I'm trying to use a hashmap to replace the content of the node "rdf:ID" with a new value as well as any "rdf:resource" contetn where the string fits.
I have generated the following code.

```
        try{
        for (Map.Entry <String, String>  rdfIdLookUp : RDF_Mapping.rdfSystemMappingMemory.entrySet()){
            xmlResult = content.replaceAll(rdfIdLookUp.getKey().toString(),rdfIdLookUp.getValue().toString());
            System.out.println (rdfIdLookUp.getKey().toString());
            System.out.println (rdfIdLookUp.getValue().toString());
        }
        FileWriter writer2 = new FileWriter(prop.getProperty("OutputDirectory")+"\\New"+filePath);
        writer2.write(xmlResult);
        writer2.close();
```

I have not been able to have the replaceAll to do the job. I have played around and looked for something like "cim:Breaker" string and the replace worked for that.
Is there something special about the strings?

Comment: Aren't you overwriting xmlresult in the loop with every iteration, and therefore only saving the last change?

Comment: Yep, thanks... sometimes it just needs another pair of eyes looking at it... :-) added a line where content gets refreshed with the latest xmlResult and now I get the right stuff...

Comment: Will create an answer

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop you are overwriting the variable xmlcontent with every iteration.

This mean that you will write to file just the last iteration's modification, i.e. the replaceAll for the last entry in the map.